# python program runs in pycharm but not in terminal

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, version, pyinstaller

I am a complete beginner to python having only previously programmed in BASIC back in the 80s. As BASIC no longer seems to be used I looked for what seemed to be the easiest programming language.

I wrote a first version of a simple python program (or maybe you call it "code" nowadays) called "laclatest" in Pycharm after following Youtube tutorials. This code runs in the Pycharm  IDE using python version 3.6. I am using an Acer laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS.

However using Pyinstaller in the terminal to generate an executable and typing ./laclatest in the Dist directory where the Pyinstaller output is to be found generates an error following the first input (input="Kitchen").

```
Enter name of room: kitchen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "laclatest.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'kitchen' is not defined
[27846] Failed to execute script laclatest
```

I tried compiling other very simple example python code (hello world type stuff from tutorials) and they run.

I suspect somehow the problem is that Pycharm is using a different version of Python to the terminal.

Can any one give me some assistance (remember I am a beginner) to get this working?. I know similar issues have been raised in the past and read them all but I have not yet been able to find a clear solution to this issue that works.

Obviously programs that only work in the IDE are not so useful.

```
#input main rooms and dimension
answer = "y"
mainroom = []
mainside1 = []
mainside2 = []
mainarea = []
print("This program calculates living area; we will start with the main rooms, i.e. ")
print("living, kitchen, bed, bath, WC, hall, landing, play, dining, storage,guest")
print ("do NOT count cellar, washing, drying, heating, garage, shed, business rooms.")


while answer.lower() == "y":
    mainroom.append((input("Enter name of room: ")))
    mainside1.append(float(input("Enter first side length in m: ")))
    mainside2.append(float(input("Enter second side length in m: ")))
    answer = input("do you have another room to enter y/n? ")

# input terraces and balconies and dimensions
answer = "y"
nonmainroom = []
nonmainside1 = []
nonmainside2 = []
nonmainarea = []

answer = input("do you have a terrace and balcony to enter y/n ")

while answer.lower() == "y":

    nonmainroom.append((input("Enter name, e.g. balcony or terrace: ")))
    nonmainside1.append(float(input("Enter first side length in m: ")))
    nonmainside2.append(float(input("Enter second side length in m: ")))
    answer = input("do you have another balcony or terrace to enter y/n? ")
Main_List_length = len(mainside1)
nonMain_List_length = len(nonmainside1)

#calculate areas of main rooms and total main areas
i=0
maintotalarea=0
while i < Main_List_length:
    a=float(mainside1[i]) * float(mainside2[i])
    print("The following room", mainroom[i], "has sides of length ", mainside1[i], "and", mainside2[i], "and a total area of", float(a))
    maintotalarea=maintotalarea + a
    i += 1

# calculate areas of non-main spaces and total non-main areas
i = 0
nonmaintotalarea = 0
while i < nonMain_List_length:
        a = (float(nonmainside1[i]) * float(nonmainside2[i]))/4
        print("The following space", nonmainroom[i], "has sides of length ", nonmainside1[i], "and", nonmainside2[i],
              "and a total area of", float(a))
        nonmaintotalarea = nonmaintotalarea + a
        i += 1
#and print the final result
else:
        print("the total area of all living space is; ", float(maintotalarea)+float(nonmaintotalarea))
```

import sys ;
print(sys.version)

in the terminal i get:

2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0]

in pycharm I get:

3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]

Process finished with exit code

```
pyinstaller --help
usage: pyinstaller [-h] [-v] [-D] [-F] [--specpath DIR] [-n NAME]
                   [--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]
                   [--add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [-p DIR]
                   [--hidden-import MODULENAME]
                   [--additional-hooks-dir HOOKSPATH]
                   [--runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS] [--exclude-module EXCLUDES]
                   [--key KEY] [-d {all,imports,bootloader,noarchive}] [-s]
                   [--noupx] [--upx-exclude FILE] [-c] [-w]
                   [-i <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns>]
                   [--version-file FILE] [-m <FILE or XML>] [-r RESOURCE]
                   [--uac-admin] [--uac-uiaccess] [--win-private-assemblies]
                   [--win-no-prefer-redirects]
                   [--osx-bundle-identifier BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER]
                   [--runtime-tmpdir PATH] [--bootloader-ignore-signals]
                   [--distpath DIR] [--workpath WORKPATH] [-y]
                   [--upx-dir UPX_DIR] [-a] [--clean] [--log-level LEVEL]
                   scriptname [scriptname ...]

positional arguments:
  scriptname            name of scriptfiles to be processed or exactly one
                        .spec-file. If a .spec-file is specified, most options
                        are unnecessary and are ignored.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         Show program version info and exit.
  --distpath DIR        Where to put the bundled app (default: ./dist)
  --workpath WORKPATH   Where to put all the temporary work files, .log, .pyz
                        and etc. (default: ./build)
  -y, --noconfirm       Replace output directory (default:
                        SPECPATH/dist/SPECNAME) without asking for
                        confirmation
  --upx-dir UPX_DIR     Path to UPX utility (default: search the execution
                        path)
  -a, --ascii           Do not include unicode encoding support (default:
                        included if available)
  --clean               Clean PyInstaller cache and remove temporary files
                        before building.
  --log-level LEVEL     Amount of detail in build-time console messages. LEVEL
                        may be one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR,
                        CRITICAL (default: INFO).

What to generate:
  -D, --onedir          Create a one-folder bundle containing an executable
                        (default)
  -F, --onefile         Create a one-file bundled executable.
  --specpath DIR        Folder to store the generated spec file (default:
                        current directory)
  -n NAME, --name NAME  Name to assign to the bundled app and spec file
                        (default: first script's basename)

What to bundle, where to search:
  --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
                        Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to
                        the executable. The path separator is platform
                        specific, ``os.pathsep`` (which is ``;`` on Windows
                        and ``:`` on most unix systems) is used. This option
                        can be used multiple times.
  --add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
                        Additional binary files to be added to the executable.
                        See the ``--add-data`` option for more details. This
                        option can be used multiple times.
  -p DIR, --paths DIR   A path to search for imports (like using PYTHONPATH).
                        Multiple paths are allowed, separated by ':', or use
                        this option multiple times
  --hidden-import MODULENAME, --hiddenimport MODULENAME
                        Name an import not visible in the code of the
                        script(s). This option can be used multiple times.
  --additional-hooks-dir HOOKSPATH
                        An additional path to search for hooks. This option
                        can be used multiple times.
  --runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS
                        Path to a custom runtime hook file. A runtime hook is
                        code that is bundled with the executable and is
                        executed before any other code or module to set up
                        special features of the runtime environment. This
                        option can be used multiple times.
  --exclude-module EXCLUDES
                        Optional module or package (the Python name, not the
                        path name) that will be ignored (as though it was not
                        found). This option can be used multiple times.
  --key KEY             The key used to encrypt Python bytecode.

How to generate:
  -d {all,imports,bootloader,noarchive}, --debug {all,imports,bootloader,noarchive}
                        Provide assistance with debugging a frozen
                        application. This argument may be provided multiple
                        times to select several of the following options.

                        - all: All three of the following options.

                        - imports: specify the -v option to the underlying
                          Python interpreter, causing it to print a message
                          each time a module is initialized, showing the
                          place (filename or built-in module) from which it
                          is loaded. See
                          https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id4.

                        - bootloader: tell the bootloader to issue progress
                          messages while initializing and starting the
                          bundled app. Used to diagnose problems with
                          missing imports.

                        - noarchive: instead of storing all frozen Python
                          source files as an archive inside the resulting
                          executable, store them as files in the resulting
                          output directory.

  -s, --strip           Apply a symbol-table strip to the executable and
                        shared libs (not recommended for Windows)
  --noupx               Do not use UPX even if it is available (works
                        differently between Windows and *nix)
  --upx-exclude FILE    Prevent a binary from being compressed when using upx.
                        This is typically used if upx corrupts certain
                        binaries during compression. FILE is the filename of
                        the binary without path. This option can be used
                        multiple times.
```

Comment: i added the output- looks like proof? but how do you get the terminal to use the new version of python without adversely affecting other terminal operation (which might rely on the old python)

Comment: @Steve ***"how do you get the terminal to use the new version of python "***: Type `python3 <your script py>` or there must be a option to tell `pyinstaller` to use `python3`.

Comment: its not obvious how to tell pyinstaller to use python3 I added the output of pyinstaller --help above (omitting windows/mac specific and rarely used options). Python3  <my script.py> runs my code correctly in the terminal

Comment: I got it working finally- not sure exactly how to be honest and whether it is correct - I installed anaconda and pip and then installed pyinstaller again using the command "conda install -c acellera pyinstaller" that I found somewhere. now pyinstaller uses python3.7

Comment: the command "python systest.py" to compile the pythion script "import sys ; print(sys.version)" now gives
3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] in terminal so it looks like the default has been changed.

Comment: ***"the default has been changed."***: Yes thats the case.